# MVC3 using BeginForm on IE9 Needs to submit twice before contoller gets called

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery, razor

I have a form that uses Html.BeginForm and for most cases this works as you would expect.

But in some situations I display a partialview that does several ajax calls to populate itself. When the partial view has been displayed I need to click the submit button twice to get the form to post. On the first click I can see the form refresh, and then on the second click the form actually posts. This is when using IE9, using Firefox the posts work on the first click.

I would like to know if anyone has seen this behaivor before I spend a lot of time trying figure this out.

Comment: If you examine the result with Fiddler or a similar tool, what is being submitted to the server on the initial clik when using IE9?

Answer (score 1):

Install [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/), open it up, and then reproduce the issue in IE. Fiddler will capture all of the requests, so you can see exactly what was sent to the server (and back).

Comment: I just hate fighting these problems, Fiddler is a good idea. Prior to this I changed the Html.BeginForm to Ajax.BeginForm (which is what it should have been in the first place) and IE9 is now happy. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar issue. The reason was, we had a  in view and in addition we were doing `$('#form').submit()` as well. But the button didn't have "`type`" attribute. After setting button `type=button`. It was good.